# MinGW cannot find my installed zlib.h and zlib files when using mingw32-make to install RSEM

Tags: windows, mingw, zlib, samtools

I have looked for hours and cannot seem to find an answer to my issue.  I have installed zlib using the sources from zlib.net with `mingw32-make -fwin32/Makefile.gcc && mingw32-make install -fwin32/Makefile.gcc` like it says in the the Makefile.gcc file as well as trying to install via `mingw-get install zlib` and `mingw-get install zlib-dev` and the correct files get into the compile folders:

```
cp -fp zlib.h '/mingw/include'
cp -fp zconf.h '/mingw/include'
cp -fp libz.a '/mingw/lib'
```

But then I try to compile RSEM version 1.3.1 via `mingw32-make` and for some reason mingw cannot find the zlib.h file when it is literally in the `C:\MinGW\include` folder.  Where can I can my MinGW build machine path?

Here are my results:

```
RSEM-1.3.1$ mingw32-make
g++  -o rsem-extract-reference-transcripts extractRef.o
g++  -o rsem-synthesis-reference-transcripts synthesisRef.o
g++  -o rsem-preref preRef.o
g++  -o rsem-build-read-index buildReadIndex.o
g++  -o rsem-simulate-reads simulation.o
cd samtools-1.3 && ./configure --without-curses && C:/Perl64/site/lib/auto/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile samtools
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking location of HTSlib source tree... htslib-1.3
checking for zlib.h... no
checking for inflate in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib development files not found

Samtools uses compression routines from the zlib library <http://zlib.net>.
Building samtools requires zlib development files to be installed on the build
machine; you may need to ensure a package such as zlib1g-dev (on Debian or
Ubuntu Linux) or zlib-devel (on RPM-based Linux distributions) is installed.

FAILED.  This error must be resolved in order to build samtools successfully.
./configure: line 38: sort: No such file or directory
./configure: line 35: sed: No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** [samtools-1.3/samtools] Error 1
```